# How does Bayes' rule on two exponentials suggest a sigmoid?

Tags: bayesian, mathematical-statistics, posterior, sigmoid-curve

In [Platt's 1999 paper](http://www.cs.colorado.edu/~mozer/Teaching/syllabi/6622/papers/Platt1999.pdf) on turning support vector machine output into a probabilistic score, he says

> Bayes rule on two exponentials suggests using a parametric form of a sigmoid

where he cites [this paper](https://web.stanford.edu/~hastie/Papers/2class.ps).  I'm still getting up to speed on Bayesian probability, so could someone help me do the math (or point me towards a reference that does) so I can see **how the posterior of two exponentials suggests a sigmoid**?

To get started, I've tried working through [this thesis](http://library.iugaza.edu.ps/thesis/118809.pdf) and looking at specific questions [like this one](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/182074/calculating-bayesian-posterior-distribution-for-an-exponential-distribution), but I must be missing something fundamental because I can't even get started on the problem.

Comment: I also found [this paper](https://www.cs.princeton.edu/~bee/courses/lec/lec_jan24.pdf) which appears to derive the posterior distribution from an exponential prior on the first page, but I don't know how to relate it to Platt's statement about two priors (or if these are even similar problems).